# Spring MVC Tomcat - 415 server refused request because request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat

**What I am trying to do:**
I am writing a Java Spring MVC REST API. I am trying to send a JSON, and based on that data get an image back.

**What my problem is**
When I send the JSON, given below, as part of the POST body with the Content-Type of `application/json`, I get the 415 error listed below

**What I have tried**

- switching `@RestController` to a `@Controller`
- switching `@RequestBody` to `@ModelAttribute`
- I am using PostMan to send the data. I include the header `Content-Type` to `application/json` so it SHOULD be sending it as JSON data. Fiddler seems to confirm this.

**Error code:**
`The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.`

---

**Controller code:**

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/GrabImage", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public byte[] GrabImage(@RequestBody Count count){
        //code will go here
    }
}
```

**JSON data:**

```
{
  "wordCounts": [
    {
      "word": "Sierra",
      "count": 50
    },
    {
      "word": "Love",
      "count": 25
    },
    {
      "word": "Dog",
      "count": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

**Count class:**

```
public class Count
{
    private WordCounts[] wordCounts;

    public WordCounts[] getWordCounts ()
    {
        return wordCounts;
    }

    public void setWordCounts (WordCounts[] wordCounts)
    {
        this.wordCounts = wordCounts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [wordCounts = "+wordCounts+"]";
    }
}
```

**WordCount class:**

```
public class WordCounts
{
    private int count;

    private String word;

    public int getCount ()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount (int count)
    {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getWord ()
    {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord (String word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [count = "+count+", word = "+word+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: suppose you need to use `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: try with this `public @ResponseBody byte[] GrabImage(@RequestBody Count count){
         code will go here
    }`

Comment: That yielded the same error. I didn't expect it to work because that concerns the RESPONSE body. What is happening is that the RequestBody isn't getting properly mapped, at least from how I see it.

Comment: Do you have `Jackson` in your classpath?

Comment: @RossiRobinsion no, I shouldn't need it though, right? What would it do for me?

Comment: You need it. If you are using maven, add the necessary `Jackson` dependencies, so that Spring uses it to `Serialize` and `Deserialize` `JSON` <-> `Java`

Comment: Do you have a good link on how to implement it? I am unfamiliar with how it works. I have used annotations in C# libraries to specify what needs to be serialized, but I assumed that @RequestBody took care of that by analyzing the names.

Comment: Figured it out. Apparently only Jackson dependencies are needed and Spring picks them up automatically? No additional tags or annotations are needed. No extra code at all. Interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rossi Robinson who helped me figure out what was wrong.

It turns out that Spring MVC requires the Jackson library to deserialize and serialize the objects. Only the dependencies will be added, and then I think Spring picks up on their existence and utilizes them.

So to ye who come here from the future: try adding the Jackson libraries if you haven't done so already.